# How to fetching data with php from a website and put its data to variable?

Tags: php, fetch, explode

I am going to read a website data and put its data in a variable.

```
$site=file_get_contents($url);
```

I am going to work with $site variable and read data from $url:

for example I am going to fetch data from this url 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States

How Should I do it?

I used explode function but I want to get center of a div for example when there is a div I need to get what is in div

```
<div id="div1">
...I need to get here between open and close tag of div
</div>
```

Comment: You say you used an explode function, could we get your php code so that we can improve / correct it? Using the explode function certainly is a possible solution. You could also use regular expression, which might be faster and shorter.

Comment: I used HTML dom to do a similar task. It worked well for me.
<http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/> Hope this helps.

Comment: before I help, stop trying to make fetch happen. now...`what are you going to do with it? because there could be a better solution that wasnt thought of. I can't see anything that won't be too quick, however parsing through it seems good. you could make a rudimentary tag parser to look for div, or doing as @Rsauxil suggested and use regexs (which i recommend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
<?php
$url = "http://somesite.com/";

$begining_match = '<body>';
$end_match = '</body>';

$file_contents = file_get_contents($url);

$extracted_contens = preg_replace("/\$begining_match([a-z0-9\.])\$end_match/i", "\\1", $file_contents);

echo $extracted_contents;
?>
```

Taken from: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?37464-possible-to-have-file_get_contents-only-grab-between-two-things